# Не срабатывает цикл for при обходе массива

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

не могу понять в чем проблема.
Смотрим простой код:

```js
var nabor = $('#category');
var items = $('#items');
var data = {
  "Набор услуг A": ['1 Услуга из набора A', '2 Услуга из набора A', '3 Услуга из набора A'],
  "Набор услуг B": ['1 Услуга из набора B', '2 Услуга из набора B', '3 Услуга из набора B'],
}
var uslugi = Object.keys(data);

for (var i = 0; i < uslugi.length; i++) {
  nabor.append('<p>' + uslugi[i] + '</p>');
}

$('#category p').on('click', function() {
  var uslugiiznabora = data[$(this).text()];
  console.log(uslugiiznabora);
  items.length = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < uslugiiznabora.length; i++) {
    items.append('<p>' + uslugiiznabora[i] + '</p>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Все идет хорошо до последнего цикла for (var i = 0; i < uslugiiznabora.length; i++) - именно он не отрабатывает, т.е. данные не выводятся. Смотрите, если до цикла выполнить следующие, например: `items.append('<p>' +uslugiiznabora[0]+ '</p>')`, что по сути выводит данные первого элемента. Но вот почему не срабатывает этот цикл - не могу понять.

Comment: Отредактируйте ваше сообщение. Добавьте `$('#category')` и `$('#items')`

Comment: Убери строку   `items.length = 0;`

Comment: Вот она, невнимательность))) Спасибо!!!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста

Comment: В продолжении темы, подскажите, как мне теперь правильно сделать, чтобы данные брались из фала json? Знаю. что нужно использовать функцию  $.getJSON, но пока не разобрался. как мне правильно получить именно тот массив, который нужен (как в примере выше) мы помещаем в переменную var uslugi = Object.keys(data);

Comment: Не надо мешать кучу вопросов в одном. Это уже другой вопрос. Этот вопрос правь обратно и задай новый...